# Zurb responsive image size doesn't work

Tags: responsive-design, image-resizing, zurb-foundation

I use zurb and I have 1 row and 4 columns and I have 4 images inside those 4 columns.
Images are not all of the same size, so in prior to get pictures 100% sharpness, I have to give them width and height for each.

I would like to ask which class do I have to use and how, that would make my images responsive(ratio) while I am decreasing the size of my browser window, and with that, size of columns, which are responsive?

This is my code:

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="three columns">
      <img src="something.jpg" style="width:220px; height:200px;" />
   </div>
   <div class="three columns">
      <img src="something.jpg" style="width:223px; height:190px;" />
   </div>
   <div class="three columns">
      <img src="something.jpg" style="width:210px; height:150px;" />
   </div>
   <div class="three columns">
      <img src="something.jpg" style="width:210px; height:195px;" />
   </div>
</div>
```

I don't use inline CSS, it's just an example for width and height.

Thank you.

Comment: I somehow had this part commented inside .css:

    /* line 45, ../../../../../../../../Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/zurb-foundation-3.0.4/stylesheets/foundation/grid.scss */
    img, object, embed {
      max-width: 100%;
      height: auto;
    }

With this my images are responsive.

Comment: Just mark you own question as answered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I somehow had this part commented inside .css:

```
/* line 45, ../../../../../../../../Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/zurb-foundation-3.0.4/stylesheets/foundation/grid.scss */
img, object, embed {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

With this my images are responsive.